# Angular onSubmit method gives a "get(...).value.split is not a function" error on Form Edit

Tags: html, angular, forms, split

Form gives a "get(...).value.split is not a function" error when onSubmit method is called in edit.

// Form's onSubmit() method

```
onSubmitRecipe(f: FormGroup) {
    // Convert string of ingredients to string[] by ','
    console.log('ID in modal before submitting is: ' + this.id);
    console.log("Ingredients: " + f.get('ingredients').value);
    let data = {
      "id": this.id,
      "imageLink": f.get('imageLink').value,
      "name": f.get('recipeName').value,
      "description": f.get('description').value,
      "ingredients": f.get('ingredients').value.split(','), // TODO: Somehow errors out when no value is input by the user when submitting the form
      "timeNeeded": f.get('timeNeeded').value,
      "favourite": f.get('favourite').value,
    }
...
```

// Form HTML

```
<ion-item>
            <ion-label position="floating">Ingredients: <ion-text color="danger">*</ion-text>
            </ion-label>
            <ion-input required formControlName="ingredients" type="text" placeholder="Split ingredients with a comma ','"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

Should expect a string[].

If I press in the input/edit the ingredients, the form can be submitted fine. It only errors out when I edit the form without touching that ingredients' input.

Error:

```
f.get(...).value.split is not a function
    at RecipeModalPage.onSubmitRecipe (recipe-modal.page.ts:91)
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (RecipeModalPage.html:65)
    at handleEvent (core.js:34789)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:36407)
    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:36043)
    at dispatchEvent (core.js:22533)
    at core.js:33721
    at HTMLElement.<anonymous> (platform-browser.js:1789)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:391)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:30885)
```

Comment: how do you call onSubmit?

Comment: `
<form [formGroup]="addRecipeForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmitRecipe(addRecipeForm)">
`

Comment: What do you get when you `console.log(f.get('ingredients').value)` without editing?

Comment: where you initialize your form? i think it happens because your not initializing it.

Comment: I get (2) ["ingredient 1", " ingredient 2"] which is what I want to submit on onSubmit(). It works if I delete\change\add ingredients in the form but errors out if i don't do anything to it. Not sure why it happens but it happens.

Comment: Added an answer, please see

Comment: The code we are seing, should work, but the code is not a [mcve]. Best would be if you could create a Stackblitz for this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your problem is want to solve ingredients null and it should be have string or solve split error.

> I will answer for solve split error

```
"ingredients": f.get('ingredients') ? f.get('ingredients').value.split(','): [],
```

Change your object key ingredients line to above code.

Comment: there's already a value for it. Just that if I don't modify it (touch the form), the error comes up. If I edit the ingredients from 'eggs' to 'eggs, bread' or 'egg', the form doesn't error out when I run the onSubmit() method. If I don't, it errors out.